# Variable into mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

ok this is driving me crazy..

```
function(amount){

matchingOrder = Order.findOne({
        Price: {
          $lte: amount
        }
      }, {
        sort: {
          Price: 1,
          Order_ID: 1
        }
      });

}
```

-----does not work

this works:

```
function(){

amount = 2

matchingOrder = Order.findOne({
        Price: {
          $lte: amount
        }
      }, {
        sort: {
          Price: 1,
          Order_ID: 1
        }
      });

}
```

in both cases console.log(amount) is 2 so variable gets passed

...sorry for maybe obvious scope or something..im relativly new at this

Comment: Define "does not work"?

Comment: How are you calling this? It is an anon function so maybe there is a problem in how you are assigning its parameter?

Comment: Maybe weird case of semicolon insertion? Try inserting semicolon after amount = 2 just to be sure...and use var while you are at it, if the variable is not defined with var somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing coming to my mind could be different types for amount. Try this instead:

```
function(amount){

matchingOrder = Order.findOne({
        Price: {
          $lte: parseInt(amount)
        }
      }, {
        sort: {
          Price: 1,
          Order_ID: 1
        }
      });

}
```

Comment: It is better to check the type at the beginning, because like this if parseInt returns NaN and you execute the query, you waste your DB's time on useless query.

Answer (score 0):

```
function query_am(input){

 var amount = input; //pay attention, as pre-condition your input must be a number.

 matchingOrder = Order.findOne({
    Price: {
      $lte: amount
    }
  }, {
    sort: {
      Price: 1,
      Order_ID: 1
    }
  });
```

}

To invoke this function, for example: query_am(2) or query_am(6) . don't do query_am('6')

Comment: for checking if number is indeed a number, check out this spectacular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/671457